# Highlight the active tab in the navigation menu bar

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightningnavigation, navigation-menu

I have this requirement of highlighting the active tab in the custom navigation menu, below is the code.
Can someone suggest how to highlight the particular bar to differentiate.

**navbar.html**

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <template for:each={menuItems} for:item="menuItem">
            <li key={menuItem.id} onclick={handleNavigation}  class="slds-p-top_xx-small">
                <a data-target={menuItem.target}>{menuItem.label}</a>
            </li>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

**navbar.js**

```js
import { LightningElement} from 'lwc'; import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class PRM_NavigationCompPCC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    menuItems = [
        { id: 1, label: 'Home', target: '/newAdmin/s/ddr' },
        { id: 2, label: 'Opportunity', target: '/newAdmin/s/opportunity/Opportunity/Default' },
        { id: 3, label: 'Reports', target: '/newAdmin/s/report/Report/Recent' },
        { id: 4, label: 'Bulk Upload', target: '/newAdmin/s/bulkupload' }
    ];


    handleNavigation(event) {
        const target = event.target.dataset.target;
        this.template.querySelector('li').activeTabValue = target;
        if (target) {
            this.navigateToPage(target);
        }
    }

    navigateToPage(pageUrl) {
        window.location.href = pageUrl;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hello , is this discussion answer your query [Visualforce tab highlight in lightning experience](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174530/visualforce-tab-highlight-in-lightning-experience?rq=1) ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code:

HTML:

```
  <template>
        <div style="width: 320px;">
            <lightning-vertical-navigation>
                <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Home" name="home" href="/newAdmin/s/ddr">
                </lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
    
                <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Opportunity" name="opportunity"
                    href="/newAdmin/s/opportunity/Opportunity/Default">
                </lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
    
                <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Reports" name="reports" href="/newAdmin/s/report/Report/Recent">
                </lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
    
                <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Bulk Upload" name="bulk_upload" href="/newAdmin/s/bulkupload">
                </lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
            </lightning-vertical-navigation>
        </div>
    </template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement} from 'lwc'; 

export default class NavBarLWC extends LightningElement{}
```

Output:
[image]

Hope this will be working as I understand your requirements.